# Packages not running completely in execute package task

Tags: ssis

There are 5 packages in my SSIS project (A,B,C,D,E) and I want them to run serially.

For that, I created a new package (F) and used EXECUTE PACKAGE TASK to combine all these 5 packages serially through precedence constraint.

After the execution of first package (A), the package (F) goes stop without the execution of the other 4 packages.

When I exclude the package A and start the process from B, then all the four packages are running fine serially but when I start from A then again the package goes stops after the execution of Package A.

Please suggest is there any issue in package A? 
I have checked the property of the package and all looks fine.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried to test your scenario. It seems to be working fine. 
1. I created A, B, C, D packages with script tasks displaying a messagebox with package name. 
2. Then I created package E with 4 Execute Package Task. Change the "PackageNameFromProjectReference" option sequentially as required.

[image]

This executes the packages in sequence A-B-C-D. Make sure that you have added the password if your package A has a password.

Comment: Thanks boss @SSharma.. Actually there was some logging issue in my Package.